Compressing GeoTiff with Rasterio
I am trying to process several GeoTiffs from Landsat satellite.
I wrote a function for clipping and then wanted to use compression on the output bands. However I try it, the compression is just not working and the output image is the same as without compression.
Looking in QGIS it also does not show any compression: https://i.sstatic.net/otEi4A4i.png
My code is below:
def clipimage(maskPath, inputBand, outImgPath):

    """
    # Image clipping using a pre-prepared GeoPackage mask in the same coordinate system as the images

    maskPath = path to polygon mask
    inputBand = image to be clipped
    outImgPath = path to new cropped image

    """

    with fiona.open(maskPath, "r") as gpkg:
        shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in gpkg]

    with rasterio.open(inputBand) as src:
        out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop = True)
        out_meta = src.meta
    
    out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff", # output format GeoTiff
                    "height": out_image.shape[1],
                    "width": out_image.shape[2],
                    "transform": out_transform,
                    "compress": "lzw",
                    "tiled" : True})
    
  
    
    with rasterio.open(outImgPath, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
        dest.write(out_image)
    

   
    return





Works for me with rasterio 1.3.10.  Are you sure you are writing correctly? You seem to be setting the height to the width of the array "height": out_image.shape[2]

Thank you, that was a badly copied typo :)
